# Deploy contract with dependencies

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-deployment

I am working with Truffle on a payroll smart contract that handles payments, employee addresses, etc. Right now my structure looks something like this:

Payroll.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import './InterfacePayroll.sol';
import './EmployeeStorage.sol';
import './Token.sol';

contract Payroll is InterfacePayroll, Ownable {
using SafeMath for uint256;

//set employeeStorage to inherit methods of InterfaceEmployeeStorage
InterfaceEmployeeStorage public employeeStorage;

//set employeeToken to Token
Token public employeeToken;

//=======Modifiers
modifier validAddress(address _address){
    require (_address != 0x0);
    _;
}

modifier higherThanZero(uint256 _uint){
    require(_uint > 0);
    _;
}

//=======Initialize
//contructor initializes an instance of EmployeeStorage
//Gas limit has to be raised manually
//TODO set gas limit internally
function Payroll() public{
    setEmployeeStorage(new EmployeeStorage());
    setEmployeeToken(new Token());
}

//set employeeStorage to contract EmployeeStorage
function setEmployeeStorage(address _newEmployeeStorage) 
internal
onlyOwner validAddress(_newEmployeeStorage){
    employeeStorage = InterfaceEmployeeStorage(_newEmployeeStorage);
}

//set employeeToken to Token contract
function setEmployeeToken(address _newEmployeetoken)
internal
onlyOwner validAddress(_newEmployeetoken){
    employeeToken = Token(_newEmployeetoken);
}

//Accept ETH payments
function () payable public { }


//========================= Functions
//=======Add functions
//Add employee to employee storage
function addEmployee(address _address, uint256 _monthlySalary, uint256 _startDate)
public
onlyOwner
validAddress(_address)
higherThanZero(_monthlySalary){
    employeeStorage.add(_address, _monthlySalary, _startDate);
}

...
..
.

}
```

So you can see that Payroll uses an instance of Employeestorage and Token. I have tested it on Remix and it seems to be working fine. My question is, how would my `2_deploy_contracts.js` look like? Seems like it would simply be:

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var payroll = artifacts.require("./Payroll");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(payroll);
}
```

Here is my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/NFhbar/410574787dd1a31a4b69f6e7d2bd0a77) with all the code.

Comment: From eyeballing it, yes. It appears that `payroll` deploys the instances it depends on so `deploy` is that simple. You can confirm that in Remix. Is the necessary to "Create" more than one contract to get it to work?

Comment: @RobHitchens yes, in Remix after compiling, the only contract I create is Payroll and all functionalities are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If all the imports are libraries and the given contract is you main contract then use this:

```
var InterfacePayroll = = artifacts.require("./InterfacePayroll");
var EmployeeStorage= = artifacts.require("./EmployeeStorage");
var Token= = artifacts.require("./Token");
var Payroll = = artifacts.require("./Payroll");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(InterfacePayroll );
deployer.deploy(EmployeeStorage);
deployer.deploy(Token);
deployer.link(InterfacePayroll ,Payroll );
deployer.link(EmployeeStorage,Payroll );
deployer.link(Token,Payroll );
deployer.deploy(Payroll );
};
```

In short, deploy the libraries/dependencies, then link them, then deploy your favorite contract. :)

Comment: Don't I also need: 
var payroll = artifacts.require("./Payroll");

Comment: Yes you do, i missed it.

Comment: Thank you! I am still not clear why I have to link the libraries if Payroll.sol deploys the libraries internally.

Comment: how does it deploy them internally?

Comment: If you see the setEmployeeStorage and the setEmployeeToken functions they each take a new() instance of EmployeeStorage and Token thus internally deploying them, no?

Comment: No, it is only creates an instance of the contract for internal use. Deploying a contract means putting it on the blockchain. If we do not deploy the dependencies before, our main contract won't find them. Hence we link it with our main contract  after deploying them so that our main contract can find them on the blockchain for further usage. We were able to make an instance without deploying, since it was on our local machine.

Comment: I see. Then I do not understand why it works. If you load the gist I linked into remix: 
https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js&optimize=false&gist=
You only need to "Create" the Payroll contract and everything works fine. You can even see addresses of the Token and Employee contracts, what am I doing wrong?